# 2 stores - 1 Magento

Tags: multi-website

I currently have a website in Canada and everything is going very well. We would like to start shipping to the United States however we would like to use only 1 Magento.

For example:
www.abc.ca - Canadian dollar
www.abc.com - US dollar

A customer will have the ability to choose the Canadian or the USA store.
However when they are on the USA site, it will go to www.abc.com and if they are in the Canadian site, it will show www.abc.ca.
Can this be done with Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is totally possible, you will have to set up two websites on Magento.
Here is a guide on how you can achieve this.
https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

and you can have different currencies and prices set up for each website.

You could also redirect users to the store/webiste you want using an extension like this https://amasty.com/magento-geoip-redirect.html